# which one is correct well exploit or exploit well

Tags: grammaticality

I'm confused about which one is correct : **well exploit** or **exploit well** and what is the rule ?
I wanted to use it in the following sentence:

> the people didn't exploit well the resources

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A short comment first: I'd use the generic "People" rather than "The people.")

The general rule says that adverbials should come after objects, so a more correct sentence would be:

- People did not exploit the resources **well**.

"well" is quite a light adverb and perhaps a better one should be found for your sentence to sound more idiomatic, as well as semantically richer. It also does not sound nice at the end of the sentence, after a comparatively longer object like "the resources". However, note that the mentioned problem disappears with a pronoun as direct object: "People did not exploit **them** well."

I suggest revising your sentence as follows:

- People did not exploit the resources **effectively / successfully / properly**.

The rule also says that (usually one-word) adverbs of manner **can** also be placed between the subject and the verb and in the middle of verb forms consisting of more than one word, and that they **usually have to** be placed in mid position in the passive voice:

- They **quickly** exploited their advantage. (simple tense)
- The resources were not **well** exploited. (passive voice)
- The architect has **cleverly** exploited new materials. (perfect tense)
- The company is **widely** exploiting its recent discovery. (continuous tense)

Unlike longer, more meaningful adverbs like the ones above, "well" can only be found in mid position in active (non-passive) sentences when it takes an intensifier, e.g. You **very well** know who is to blame.

It also appears as forming part of compound adjectives like "well-known".

Comment: thank you for responding, concerning your note, this phrase is taken from a paragraph, in which we are talking about a specific people, people of an island, so in this case I guess I can use 'THE'

Comment: @aName Yes, in that case "the" is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sentence should be phrased

> the people didn't exploit the resources very well.

since you are trying to describe how much advantage was taken from the resources.  The equivalent would be

> the resources were not well exploited.